# Multiple selection in foreach to LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a `foreach` loop with `DataSet` (`ds`), `CsvFileData` is a generic type having three fields: `InvestmentAgaID` ,`InvestmentCode` ,`HasPosition` which are `string`s. `CSVDataList` is a list of `CsvFileData`.

Now I want to convert it into LINQ rather than `foreach`.

```
foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    CsvFileData ob = new CsvFileData();

    ob.InvestmentAgaID = drow[1].ToString().Trim();
    ob.InvestmentCode = drow[0].ToString().Trim();
    ob.HasPosition = drow[2].ToString().Trim();
    CSVDataList.Add(ob);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var data = ds.Tables[0].Rows
.Cast<DataRow>()
.Select(x => new CsvFileData() 
{
    InvestmentAgaID = x[1].ToString().Trim(),
    InvestmentCode = x[0].ToString().Trim(),
    HasPosition = x[2].ToString().Trim()
})
.ToList();
```